# How to reset the in memory database in tests with play2, slick3, specs2

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, slick, specs2

This is about a play 2.4 app with slick 3.1 using specs 2.
I use an in-memory db with evolutions during my tests. My problem is this: At the moment, the in-memory database is kept alive for all the tests and is not reset to the initial empty state after each test case.

My current code looks like this:

```
package test

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import services.ProjectService
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import org.specs2.mutable._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import testhelpers.Injector


class ModelSpec extends Specification {

  import models._

  val projectService = Injector.inject[ProjectService]

  "A project" should {

    "be inserted" in {
      running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {

        val action = projectService.create("A")
          .flatMap(_ => projectService.all)

        val result = Await.result(action, Duration.Inf)

        result must be_==(List(Project(1, "A")))
      }
    }

    "be inserted2" in {
      running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {

        val action = projectService.create("A")
          .flatMap(_ => projectService.all)

        val result = Await.result(action, Duration.Inf)

        result must be_==(List(Project(1, "A")))
      }
    }


  }

}
```

First test passes. Second testfails with the error: List(Project(1,A), Project(2,A)) is not equal to List(Project(1,A)) (ModelSpec.scala:42) because the in-memory database is kept between test cases.

You can find the example project here: https://github.com/nemoo/play-slick3-example

How can i have a fresh database for each test case?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Acolyte approach](http://acolyte.eu.org/) for fully isolated unit tests of JDBC based persistence layer (see [example](https://github.com/voxolab/speech-recognition-api/blob/master/test/MediaFilesSpec.scala) with Slick persistence).

Comment: Just found out that it works as expected in play 2.3 (see similar https://github.com/nemoo/democratizer/blob/master/test/ModelSpec.scala) and doesn't work in play 2.4. I don't want to add an additional dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [implementation of `imMemoryDatabase`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/702e89841fc54f5603a0d981c3488ed9883561fe/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L98-L108):

```
  def inMemoryDatabase(name: String = "default", options: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String]): Map[String, String] = {
    val optionsForDbUrl = options.map { case (k, v) => k + "=" + v }.mkString(";", ";", "")

    Map(
      ("db." + name + ".driver") -> "org.h2.Driver",
      ("db." + name + ".url") -> ("jdbc:h2:mem:play-test-" + scala.util.Random.nextInt + optionsForDbUrl)
    )
  }
```

You can see it's setting `db.whatever` config values, but [Play Slick uses `slick.dbs.whatever`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick#Database-Configuration), so this won't help you. Here's what Play Slick uses:

```
# Default database configuration
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

You'll probably want to create your own `inMemorySlickDatabase` (using the implementation of `inMemoryDatabase` as inspiration), setting the appropriate config values.

Comment: Ok, i tried that. created my own inMemorySlickDatabase and used it in the tests. The problem still is the same. The first test passes, the second fails with the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own def to set things up for slick/h2, and that seemed to work ok.

i.e.

```
  def inMemoryDatabaseSlick(name: String = "default", options: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String]): Map[String, String] = {
val optionsForDbUrl = options.map { case (k, v) => k + "=" + v }.mkString(";", ";", "")

Map(
  ("slick.dbs." + name + ".driver") -> "slick.driver.H2Driver$",
  ("slick.dbs." + name + ".db.driver") -> "org.h2.Driver",
  ("slick.dbs." + name + ".db.url") -> ("jdbc:h2:mem:play-test-" + scala.util.Random.nextInt + optionsForDbUrl)
)
```

}

However the problem I have now is that my H2 DB is empty, and I can't see any attempt to apply the evolutions to it, to populate it. Should I expect this to work? Or should I expect to create the tables myself?

Comment: In play 2.3 it worked that i got a fresh database with the evolutions applied for each test case. You can find a working play 2.3 example here: https://github.com/nemoo/democratizer/blob/master/test/IsolationSpec.scala